# When using bulk collect in function then issue during db migration from oracle to postgres

Tags: sql, database, oracle, postgresql, database-migration

**What should be alternate way of  bulk collect and Type  in  postgres function during dbmigration ?**

**Oracle function :-**

```
create or replace 
    FUNCTION FN_SL_PERF_WITH_CRIT_ANO()
       RETURN NUMBER  AS
       var_decl_cnt NUMBER ;
       var_inter_cnt NUMBER ;
     Type declaration_table is table of varchar2(100);
       var_declarationId_table declaration_table;
       cursor cursor1 is
      SELECT distinct(DECLARATION_ID) 
       FROM
       (SELECT DECL.DECLARATION_ID AS DECLARATION_ID FROM T_FLAG_NRVL FLAG.DECL;
                 );
         BEGIN
            var_inter_cnt := 0;
            open cursor1;
            fetch cursor1 bulk collect into var_declarationId_table;
            close cursor1;
            var_decl_cnt := var_declarationId_table.count;
        RETURN NVL(var_decl_cnt,0);
       EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE||SQLERRM);
       RETURN NVL(VAR_DECL_CNT,0);
       END FN_SL_PERF_WITH_CRIT_ANO;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching and syntax I have converted oracle query in PostgreSQL using two way :-
**1) Using Cursor
2)Using for For loop**

**For loop example :-**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_sl_perf_without_crit_ano()
  RETURNS bigint AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
  var_decl_cnt bigint := 0 ;
  var_inter_cnt bigint := 0 ;
 v_sql_dynamic varchar :=  'SELECT distinct(DECLARATION_ID)  
  FROM
  (
    SELECT DECL.DECLARATION_ID AS DECLARATION_ID FROM T_FLAG_NRVL FLAG.DECL;)anr';

v_sql_dynamic_count varchar :='select count(*)  from ('||v_sql_dynamic||')an1 ';
    myvar  RECORD;

BEGIN
 EXECUTE v_sql_dynamic_count into var_decl_cnt;
  raise notice 'var_decl_cnt%',var_decl_cnt ;  
if var_decl_cnt > 0 then 
FOR myvar IN EXECUTE v_sql_dynamic
LOOP
         select count(1) into var_inter_cnt from T_ANOMALY_NRVL ANOMALY where ANOMALY.DECLARATION_ID = myvar.DECLARATION_ID  and ANOMALY.RISK_LEVEL IN ('3','4'); 
        if var_inter_cnt > 0  THEN
       raise notice 'var_inter_cnt%',var_inter_cnt ;  
         var_decl_cnt := var_decl_cnt-1;
        END IF;
  END LOOP;
end if ;
    if(var_countdec != 0) then
       var_decl_cnt:= round((var_decl_cnt/var_countdec) *100,2);
     end if;
      raise notice 'var_decl_cnt%',var_decl_cnt ;  
 RETURN coalesce(var_decl_cnt,0) ;
END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Hope this example help to convert the query.